# Do we need sessions if we are using tokens

Tags: java, node.js, session, server, jwt

I have basic knowledge of both sessions and JWT tokens. Is there any situation where sessions are must and can't be replaced by JWT tokens. An explanation would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is confidential, JWT is not suitable because anyone can decode the information stored in JWT(but can not modify it). While with session, data is stored in server side, only the sessionId is passed between client and server, no one can steal the session data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions when you want to provide Logout functionality to the user without using any storage mechanism.

Like if you want to provide logout functionality to the user with JWT's you have to store the JWT token somewhere so that you can delete that when the user hits the Logout button.

Moreover, your session will expire when you will close your window but that does not happen in case of JWT